# Can unregistered users accept answers?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, unregistered-users

Just curious:

I answered a question and the user seems to like the answer, but hasn't accepted it. I checked his profile, and it shows "Unregistered User".

I wonder if the user can't accept the answer because they aren't registered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they can.

I deleted Koper's answer because it was 100% incorrect.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I accidentally asked a question as an unregistered user on Stack Overflow even though I have a registered account. How do I accept the answer for the question? If I go to the question without logging in to my registered account I don't seem to have the option of accepting an answer and if I go to the question logged in with my registered account I can't accept the answer because I asked it as an unregistered user and not with my registered account.

Comment: @czarak you need to have the accounts merged, email the address at the bottom of every page with URLs to both accounts